# ISO Case Validation Rule where Status = X, (A cannot be blank), and (either B or C cannot be blank)

Tags: case, validation-rule, operators

I've tried several iterations of formulas, but can't get the last section to work. It is intended that the Validation would fire when trying to change to the specific status, if the criteria were met. The criteria needed for the Validation to fire:

1. Status = Secondary Review
   AND
2. Description_of_Issue__c = blank
   AND EITHER
3. Project_Name__c = blank
   OR
4. Original_Order_Number__c = blank

Expressed another way: 1 AND 2 AND (3 OR 4)

It would also be acceptable if the rule fired for 1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 but I believe that scenario is covered with the above formula.

Here's the latest missed mark:

```
(
    ISPICKVAL ( Status, "Secondary Review" )
    &&
    OR (
        ISBLANK(Description_of_Issue__c),
        ISBLANK(Project_Name__c ),
        NOT(ISBLANK(Original_Order_Number__c ))
    )
)
||
(
    ISPICKVAL ( Status, "Secondary Review" )
    &&
    OR (
        ISBLANK(Description_of_Issue__c),
        NOT(ISBLANK(Project_Name__c )),
        ISBLANK(Original_Order_Number__c )
    )
)
||
(
    ISPICKVAL ( Status, "Secondary Review" )
    &&
    OR (
        ISBLANK(Description_of_Issue__c),
        ISBLANK(Original_Order_Number__c ),
        ISBLANK(Project_Name__c )
    )
)
```

The only version of this that works is for all fields, but that's not what I need. Any insight/help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In general, I don't recommend mixing `&&` and `||` with `AND()` and `OR()`. Choose one, and stick with it. In formulas, my preference is to use `AND()` and `OR()`

In general, if you find yourself repeating things in formulas (or in code), that's an indication that you can simplify things.

Working from a plain-language description of what you're trying to achieve is, in my opinion, a good way to go about building formulas. The issue here is in how you've translated it from "plain language" into "formula".

Using `AND()` and `OR()`, instead of composing things like

```
1 AND 2 AND (3 OR 4)
```

you compose things like

```
AND(
    1,
    2,
    OR(
        3,
        4
    )
)
```

So if your description is accurate, then the formula that you are looking for is

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Secondary Review"),
    ISBLANK(Description_of_Issue__c),
    OR(
        ISBLANK(Project_Name__c),
        ISBLANK(Original_Order_Number__c)
    )
)
```

I find it kinda hard to describe my *exact* thought process in building formulas. In this instance though, I might say that I build it from inside-out.

That is, you know that `3 OR 4` are a package deal. They can't be separated. So `OR(3,4)` becomes a single "unit" that you then use as a building block for the rest of your formula.

Comment: On a second reading, it looks like you may not be familiar with Boolean logic. `OR(1, 2)` will result in true if either `1` or `2` is true (and `AND(1, 2)` only results in true if both `1` and `2` are true). This is why you can remove the other 2 "branches" where you're checking if one is blank and the other is not blank (assuming you appropriately move the `ISBLANK(Description_of_Issue__c)` outside of the `OR()`)

Comment: Also, it's good to keep in mind that validation rules are better thought of as _invalidation_ rules. If the result is true, then the rule will complain and stop the record from being saved. If what you're describing is when your data is _valid_, then you'd just need to wrap this entire thing inside of a `NOT()` (which could be simplified using [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)).

Comment: This is awesome (thanks so much) but it didn't do what I was looking for. This formula allows the status to change with either 'Project Name' or 'Original Order Number' blank. 

To advance to the 'Secondary Review' status, we need 'Description of Issue' filled in, and either 'Project Name' OR 'Original Order Number', but both is also fine. Neither is not. 

I agree, syntax gets confusing when you are talking about making a VR file - it's an anti-rule. Also, thanks for the pointers, really appreciate that.

Comment: @ChristinHead ah, so it sounds like you don't need the `OR()` at all here, if you remove the `OR()` (but keep the stuff inside the `OR()`, so that it becomes part of the overall `AND()`, then it should work. In other words, the condition you want to prevent is when Status is "Secondary Review" AND Description of Issue is not blank AND Project Name is blank AND Original Order Number is blank.

Comment: Unfort, that gets me a VR that fires when *all* conditions are true, which is not what we are looking for.  Those last two fields are an EITHER/OR situation. We need to allow a status change to "SR", but only as long as Field 1 and EITHER Field 2 OR Field 3 are not blank. (We can have a case with no project, just a direct order to reference.) Thanks for your continued help, and if you have any other ideas, I'm all ears!

Comment: @ChristinHead I think you're making contradicting statements here. If the either/or bit was accurate, then my answer would be correct. I'll rephrase a bit of an earlier comment. Think about validation rules as a statement, "This data is invalid and must be stopped when: X". Based on what you've said, you data is invalid when Status = SR, and the description is blank, and both project and order number are blank. If either project or order number are filled in, then the change to Status = SR should be allowed, correct?

Comment: @ChristinHead About the only other way I can think of interpreting this is if "description of issue" must not be blank (i.e. it's fine if one of project/order number are blank, but "description of issue" must always be filled in).